# Code to update Lead Email ID

Tags: apex

I am new to apex coding.  I have a requirement  - the Leed email needs to be changed to an invalide one to ensure no emails are sent out to the leads (this is for one of our sandboxes.)

1. Identify leads whose email value is not null.
2. Update the email ids to 'dummyemail@email.com' or suffix it with some dummy value to make it invalid.

Guess something can be done using For loop.

Please can someone help me on this.

Kind Regards,
Manjith

Comment: Why do you need apex for this? you can simply export/import the data, clean it in csv and reupload it back using dataloader/import wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Please run below code from developer console.

```
List<Lead> listOFLead = new <Lead>();
for(Lead ld : [Select id, Email from Lead WHERE Email  != null limit 50000])
{
ld.Email = 'New invalid email id';
listOFLead .add(ld );
}

update listOFLead
```

You can use [Dataloader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) or [dataload.io](http://dataloader.io/) as Rahul suggest.

Comment: This code will simply update all the lead records in database, whatsoever

Comment: My code will update only those record where email id in not null. please update your down vote.